# 404 error for css file in media folder in django app

Tags: python, css, django, http-status-code-404

In my django app ,I have put these settings

```
settings.py
------------
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/me/dev/python/django/myproject/myapp/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/site_media/'

urls.py
--------
...
url(r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
url(r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$','django.views.static.serve',{'document_root':settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
```

I created a css file in `'/home/me/dev/python/django/myproject/myapp/media/css'` folder and included this in template as below

```
base.html
--------
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>my app</title>
<LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="{{MEDIA_URL}}css/myappstyle.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA="screen, print"/>

home.html
---------
{% extends "mywebapp/base.html" %}>
{% block title %}{{block.super}}| Home {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
   {{block.super}}
   hi
{% endblock %}
```

Then I created a view as below

```
def custom_render(request,context,template):
    req_context=RequestContext(request,context)
    return render_to_response(template,req_context)

def home(request,template_name,page_title):
    print 'home'
    return render_to_response(template_name,{'me':'myname'})
```

and set its url conf

```
myapp.urls
--------

urlpatterns=patterns('',
  url(r'^$','myapp.views.home',
      {
         'template_name':'mywebapp/home.html',
         'page_title':'Home'
       },
      name='home'),
```

when I give the url

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/
```

The web page gets rendered ,but css is not.The console output shows a 404 error

```
[14/Sep/2012 10:02:50] "GET /myapp/ HTTP/1.1" 200 547
[14/Sep/2012 10:02:50] "GET /myapp/css/myappstyle.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2514
```

But,when I give the url,

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/site_media/css/myappstyle.css
```

I can see the contents of the css file without any problems.

Why does this happen? can someone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `RequestContext()` while rendering response for `home` view also (as you have done for `custom_render` view).

Otherwise `{{MEDIA_URL}}` will be empty which will result in `404` error.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use `direct_to_template` instead of `render_to_response`. Using it, you are not have to use `RequestContext()`:

```
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template

def some_view(request):
    # ...
    return direct_to_template(request, template_name, params_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the static files, you need use

```
<LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/myappstyle.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA="screen, print"/>
```

and check then `DEBUG = True`